# URL aliases in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

what is the right method to convert:

```
www.domain.com/post/id-of-the-post
```

in this:

```
www.domain.com/post/title-of-the-post
```

Thanks

Comment: Are your routes hardcoded or generated by a database and the id-of-the-post/title-of-the-post caught in a `{{ title_or_id }}`? If they are just caught in a `{{ title_or_id }}` your could add a method in your repository to `findByTitleOrId` that searches by title and then id (or the other way around) in the same vein as https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php#L95-L109

Comment: Yes, so I suposse I can try a solution similar to that. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for alias routes yet:

[Add Support for Alias Routes in Symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6088)

You can however:

<kbd>1</kbd> Generate unique slugs for your posts. If using Doctrine, use [`slugable extension`](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#sluggable)

<kbd>2</kbd> Create a controller that takes a slug, and create routing accordingly to route to that controller via:

```
www.domain.com/post/title-of-the-post
```

<kbd>3</kbd>  Create controller that takes an id, create routing accordingly to route to that controller via:

```
www.domain.com/post/id-of-the-post
```

<kbd>4</kbd> Redirect users that visit `www.domain.com/post/id-of-the-post` to `www.domain.com/post/title-of-the-post`